# Как узнать, когда нужно удалять память?

Tags: c++, c

```
char * buf = (char*) malloc (PWD_BUF_SIZE * sizeof (char));
buf = getcwd (buf, PWD_BUF_SIZE);
...
free(buf);
```

Удалили память, потому что выделили.

```
char * buf = getcwd(NULL, PWD_BUF_SIZE);
...
free(buf)
```

Удалили память, но на этот раз мы не выделяли.

```
char f[] = "/home/user/1.txt";
char * b = basename(f);
...
free(b); // привело к ошибке.
```

Почему последний вариант привел к ошибке?

Чтобы лучше понять, нужно реализовать функцию basename. Как? Если представим, что внутри ее выделяется память через alloca, то внутри функции она должна была бы освободится.

*То есть я хочу понять, когда освобождать память, и научится создавать функции такого типа как basename, которые возвращают указатель на память, которую не нужно удалять.*

С первыми двумя примерами все понятно. Если мы передает NULL, то память выделяется автоматически размером PWD_BUF_SIZE.

Comment: @andrey1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @andrey1, в следующий раз в подобных вопросах (связанных с библиотечными функциями) указывайте (видимо в тегах) еще и ОС.

--

Что же касается (похоже, сути вопроса(?))

     ...я хочу ... научится создавать функции ..., которые возвращают указатель на память, которую не нужно удалять.

Передавайте в функцию блок памяти, в которой та сформирует результат и вернет адрес где-то внутри этого блока (обычно его начало).

По сути именно так и сделано в `basename` (только в manpage акцент на in-out характер аргумента не проставлен).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@andrey1](/users/22347/andrey1), освобождать (`free()`) можно только ту память, которая получена в результате `malloc()/calloc()/realloc()` (или функций, которые возвращают результат вызова `malloc/calloc/realloc`).

Обратите внимание, в `free` *нельзя* передавать адрес откуда-то из середины выделенного блока (только начальный адрес) и нельзя передавать его более одного раза.

Конечно, я говорю о стандартной (общепринятой) их реализации. В принципе же вполне можно представить аллокатор, хранящий адреса и размеры всех выделенных блоков, (например в rb-tree), который позволяет удалять "хвосты" (и даже расщеплять ранее выделенный блок) и безболезненно реагирует на realloc/free по неправильным адресам. Расплатой за возможность таких "вольностей"  будет потеря эффективности.

По поводу `dirname()` и `basename()`. 
Думаю, тривиальный примерчик (с печатью адресов) все ставит на свои места:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *s = "/usr/lib/",  *p = strdup(s),
    *d = dirname(p), *b = basename(p);
  printf ("s = %p\t[%s]\n"
          "p = %p\t[%s]\n"
          "d = %p\t[%s]\n"
          "b = %p\t[%s]\n",
          s, s, p, p, d, d, b, b);

  char *q = strdup(s), *n = basename(q);
  printf ("q = %p\t[%s]\n"
          "n = %p\t[%s]\n",
          q, q, n, n);

  free(p); // or free(d);
  free(q);

  return 0;
}
```

Результат запуска:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc c.c
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
s = 0x4007d8    [/usr/lib/]
p = 0x242b010   [/usr]
d = 0x242b010   [/usr]
b = 0x242b011   [usr]
q = 0x242b030   [/usr/lib]
n = 0x242b035   [lib]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Тут становится очевидно, что

```
uname -a 
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

эти функции меняют переданный аргумент (ставят нули) "по месту" (никакого копирования).

Comment: @avp, почему переменная s и переменная p имеют разные значения после strdup?

Comment: @andrey1, `p = strdup(s)` возвращает копию строки, на которую указывает `s` в памяти, которую выделяет `malloc(strlen(s) + 1)`.

Естественно, что это две разные области памяти.

--

На печати же мы видим память, на которую указывает `p` **уже после** вызова `d = dirname(p);`, которая и меняет содержимое этой памяти

(пишет 0 после `/usr` (там был до этого `'/'`)).

--

Или я не понял вопроса?

Comment: @avp спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Вы должны думать немного по-другому. Правильно думать в терминах *ответственности*: кто есть хозяин выделенной памяти?

Если Вы выделили память сами, Вы и есть её хозяин. Вы можете оставить ответственность за этот кусок памяти за собой или передать её (вместе с памятью) другому куску программы.

Если Вы вызываете функцию, тут всё немного сложнее. Функция может выделить *для Вас* кусок памяти и передать Вам права на него вместе с обязанностью освободить память. Она может, однако, передать Вам и указатель на какую-то другую память и таким образом не ставить вас перед необходимостью «убирать» за этой функцией. Но возвращённая память может ссылаться на кусок памяти из аргументов этой самой функции, так что Вы должны быть осторожны и не освободить казалось бы не связанный с результатом функции кусок памяти преждевременно.

Функция **обязана** в своей документации подробно описывать, кто хозяин памяти, которую она возвращает.

Если Вы пишете на C++ в противоположность чистому C, здесь обычно всё происходит по-другому. Пользоваться нативными указателями и думать об ответственности часто считается низкоуровневым моветоном, вместо этого пользуются указателями с автоматическим подсчётом ссылок: `shared_ptr` и `weak_ptr`. Несмотря на то, что они берут на себя большую часть работы (и незаменимы в случае, если в вашем коде встречаются исключения), всё же при неосторожном пользовании ими возможны утечки памяти при наличии кольцевых ссылок. Но это — очень длинная тема для обсуждения, не связанная с основным вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

Читайте man-ы. Для getcwd:

> As an extension to the POSIX.1-2001
> standard, Linux (libc4, libc5,  glibc)
> getcwd()
>        **allocates  the buffer dynamically using malloc(3) if buf is
> NULL**.  In this case, the
>        allocated buffer has the length size unless size is zero, when buf is 
> allocated  as
>        big as necessary.  **The caller should free(3) the returned buffer.**

Кратко, если buf == NULL, то нужно освобождать память.

Для basename:

> Both dirname() and basename() return
> pointers to null-terminated strings.
> (**Do  not
>        pass these pointers to free(3).**)

В man-е по basename также сказано, что возвращенный указатель может ссылаться на какую-то позицию в передаваемом аргументе, а может на какую-то область памяти, выделенную внутри basename (видимо, она создает глобальный буффер). И еще, что она может менять содержимое строки, которое мы передаем в качестве аргумента. Наверное, таким образом достигается возможность не выделять память для результата. Если честно, сомнительное решение, я бы не советовал так делать. Лучше сделать так, как в getcwd.

Answer (score 1):

С basename не знаком, но предположу, что он вообще не выделяет память и не копирует строку, а просто возвращает указатель на символ внутри переданной ему же строки. В нашем случае b будет равен f + 11. Естественно, освобождать этот указатель не нужно.

> как понять, когда освобождать память

Читайте руководства по используемым функциям.

P.S. хотя по basename там не все так просто:

Функция может изменять исходную строку, а может вернуть указатель на память, которая может быть перезаписана при следующем вызове basename. Функция не обязана быть реэнтерабельной или потокобезопасной.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите раз и навсегда избавиться от необходимости освобождать память, то я знаю (и применяю) два способа. Первый: использование статического массива внутри функции. Разумеется, такой метод подходит, если заранее известен максимальный объем данных.

```
char* revstr(const char* str)
{
    static char rev[STR_MAX];
    unsigned int i = strlen(str);
    assert(i < STR_MAX);
    rev[i] = '\0';
    while( i-- ) {
        rev[i] = *str++;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Второй: выделить один участок памяти и размещать все свои данные там. Такой способ хорошо подходит в случаях, когда данные надо удалять все сразу. Например, создали игровые объекты, а на следующем уровне игры очищаем весь пул памяти и снова создаем объекты.

```
typedef struct Pool {
    char pool[POOL_MAX];
    unsigned int used;
} *Pool;

void pool_reset(Pool p)
{
    p->used = 0;
}

void* pool_alloc(Pool p, const unsigned int size)
{
    char* ptr = p->pool + p->used;
    p->used += size;
    assert( p->used <= POOL_MAX );
    return ptr;
}
```

Конечно, это просто прототип, при желании можно сделать лучше - с автоматическим расширением пула, например. Можно использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку для сборки мусора. Погуглите BOEHM. Я им не пользовался, у меня нет таких сложных задач. Я применяю либо один из двух вышеупомянутых методов, либо (самый частый вариант) ни один из них. Понятно, что метод работы с памятью надо выбрать еще до написания первой строчки программы. Обычно это заранее понятно, хотя у меня был один случай, когда показалось, что нужен второй, а в результате переписал под первый. Но я очень быстро понял, и переписывать пришлось мало.